# How to improve the reads from OLTP reprocessing Dimensions Attributes in SSAS?

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

I'm working to reduce the time that we spend to reprocess our SSAS cube.

The slowest part is processing the dimension (Process update or process add),
in specific the bottleneck is when SSAS is reading from OLTP.
When I open profiler I can see the event "Read Data" and the "Integer Data" increases in chunks of 10,000. Based on this I have the following questions

1. Does SSAS read and write data in chunks of 10,000?
2. How can I increase that number?
3. Any suggestions to improve the performance?

PS I already created indexes in the source tables and increased the ThreadPool\Process\MAX Threads